# Can't get image size set with set_post_thumbnail_size() function

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a problem with set_post_thumbnail_size() function, which seems it doesn't work. Or at least it doesn't work correctly.

I have set a thumbnail size 75x75px in WordPress settings under the media section and have   also set another thumbnail size in the functions.php using:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size(80, 80, true);
```

How are these two settings supposed to work? I believe the one that I set in the function.php (80x80px) should override the other in the media settings. Am I correct?

This is not the case though. Both sizes of the image exist in my uploads folder and what is worst I can't get the one I set with set_post_thumbnail_size() no matter what.

When I call

```
the_post_thumbnail($id, 'thumbnail');
```

I get the one set in the media settings and not the one I set in my theme's functions.php. How can I get the other?

**UPDATE:** It seems I messed up 'thumbnail' and 'post-thumbnail'. In media settings I can set the thumbnail size, which is another image size as 'medium' and 'large'. Using set_post_thumbnail_size() I can set the post-thumbnail (aka featured image) size. Sorry for the mess and thanks for the answers.

Comment: as for the default thumbnail (not the custom one) I struggled to get it with the_post-thumbnail('thumbnail'), I got lucky w/o parameters: the_post-thumbnail('thumbnail')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They work independently of eachother. You need to call the one you created in the functions.php.

So in your functions.php you would have something like:

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 75, 75, true ); // default thumbnail size
add_image_size('my-custom-thumb', 80, 80, true); //custom size
}
```

and then to call your custom thumbnail you would add this where you want it to appear:

```
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail('my-custom-thumb'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the original question actually referred to thumbnail and not post-thumbnail, you can update the thumbnail size in functions.php using:

```
// we can override the defaults
update_option('thumbnail_size_w', 170);
update_option('thumbnail_size_h', 170);
```

This works for medium and large too:

```
update_option('medium_size_w', 768);
update_option('medium_size_h', 576);

update_option('large_size_w', 1020);
update_option('large_size_h', 768);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `set_post_thumbnail_size()` will not override media setting.

make sure your theme support for  post-thumbnails

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 75, 75,true );
}
```

and define the image as featured image in Edit Post and Edit Page screens
to call the post-thumbnail

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

OR

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id);
```

REF : http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails